# Can Erfworld be read skipping the text-only-updates?

Tags: webcomics, erfworld

[Erfworld](http://www.erfworld.com/) is a fair great web comic. I really enjoyed Book 1.

But after book 1 it suffered repeated misfortune with the artists.
For various reasons the artists were unable to produce comics at regular intervals. This lead to the other author to publish "Text-Updates".
Which don't have art, or only have single panel of art and then half a page or more of text.

It has been a while since I read any Erfworld and i have been thinking about trying to get up to date. I enjoy the panel comic much more than the text.
But if i only read the panel comics, would I miss out on plot crucial information? Or is the stuff in the text updates only background stuff?

Comment: Word of God trumps all, so this is not going to be an aswer, but IMHO it depends. Some text-only updates are about other stories, and those can be skipped, but others are integral to the story, like the last few chapters.

Comment: @Ciacciu - You *should* make that an answer. Not only is the author's statement no guarantee that the pages are truly supplementary, but that statement is two years old.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Good argument, done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can, up to a point**

Early text-only updates were, as you say, to make up for lack of artists; they were used both to advance the story and to expand on Erfworld's setting with other Sides in distant lands and some characters' background.

Later on there are quite a few updates which are *not* in comic form and are central to the story.

You should be able to tell the difference at a glance.

I'll add that personally I really enjoyed the text-updates, they add a whole new dimension to the setting, and flesh out the way the Sides interact with each other.

Answer (score 6):

This was covered on the [official Erfworld website](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811061926/http://www.erfworld.com/2014/08/a-note-about-format/). In short, **the author feels that the text updates are supplementary, rather than essential.**

> *But a lot of readers actually said they would miss the density of
>   information and richness of story that came with the texts. And I
>   realized that I would, too. The comic medium is great for many things,
>   but it makes certain storytelling things hard to do.*
>
> *When I was looking at this page, which was scripted as two
>   half-panels, I realized I wanted to do half-pages of text for each of
>   them. I think that’s how I ought to tell Book 3. So expect to see some
>   pages like this. **To those of you who are put off by texts, I’ll try to
>   keep to the rule that you can read comic pages only and still follow
>   the story,** and please enjoy David's illustration. Especially the two
>   gwiffons on the ground with their feedbags on*

Comment: Link is broken. Perhaps replace with link to way-back machine?

Comment: @Oxinabox - Done

Answer (score 0):

I personally enjoy the text updates and would like to see more, as they provide a heap of more information, such as the thoughts and some explanation to the actions of the characters. I can get by much more by rereading text updates while waiting for the next page. That being said, my dream of a perfect Erworkd book would be two versions, one mainly text with occasional pictures and one mainly comic with occasional text.

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment than an answer. Were the text-only sections necessary or not?

Comment: It looks like you're saying that the text-only updates can be skipped (since you suggest a book "mainly comic with occasional text"), but on the other hand you say the text updates provide "a heap of more information". So are they necessary or not?